# How to display non-series data in tooltip in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, tooltip

I have a single series being plotted on column graph. On the x-axis I plot some time values and on the y-axis I have a constant value. Basically it's just to show some time based logs.

Using `series.addPoint([x,y],false,false)` I plot the values. While I am plotting the values I have some additional info about the log which I would like to show on the tooltip. How can I pass this string of information and let the tooltip access it whenever I hover over each log entry in the chart ? I am currently able to access only the x-axis value using

```
tooltip: {
                formatter: function () {
                    console.log(this);
                    return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                    Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S.%L', this.x) + '<br/>';
                }
            }
```

My series is defined this way

```
series: [{
                name: 'Logs',
                data: [],
                stack: 'LogStack'
            }]
```

I'd really appreciate it if you could let me know the solution to my problem.

Comment: Add points as objects: `addPoint({ x: y, y: y, extra: '...' })`. Then in Tooltip you have access to that info: `var extras = this.point.options.extra;`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Pawel. I could achieve exactly what was required ! :)